# DocuSign API - C# console application - RequestJWTUserToken - error "consent_required"

Tags: docusignapi

I need advice on what I'm doing wrong. I'm calling the following block of code from a console application in C#:

```
string path = @ "C:\Temp\private.key";

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
var authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken (
"11383d14-8c83-4c61-ab4f-99d5d19bd2dd",
"476205fe-9d1a-46be-95e3-6873315ce3a9",
"account-d.docusign.com",
File.ReadAllBytes(path),
1,
new List<string>
{
   "signature",
   "impersonation"
});
```

Error is: "consent_required"

I have authentication set to "Authorization Code Grant".
What's wrong in the parameters or settings?

Thank you

Comment: So I have already found a solution. The client will need to provide consent by calling this url from the browser window: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature+impersonation&client_id=integrator_key&redirect_uri=your_encoded_redirect_url
Don't be angry, but it wasn't clear from the documentation.
It would be possible to automate this process by calling another method, if it is not a website, but is it a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

This is right, you need to obtain consent and we have plenty of documentation about it.

- https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent
- https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

If still you feel some documentation is not clear about JWT consent - can you let me know which one?

Comment: Thank you, the first link could answer my questions, I was not very wise from the official documentation. What came to me, a bit incomprehensible from the position of a desktop application developer, is that I call a method, give it all the login details, and yet I still have to visit some websites where I have to confirm something else? This does not seem very intuitive to me, which is why my question is whether this process could not be simplified.

Comment: So if not, I'll have to come up with a method to force the client to visit this site, I'll open a browser with this link, but all other happenings will be out of my control. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: this is only needed once. Once you do that correctly - you never have to do this again.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for this useful information